# Batch variables do not work?

Tags: batch-file

So I have this simple script:

```
@echo off
set /p "derp = Enter thing here >> "
echo %derp%
pause >nul
```

But when I run it:

```
Enter thing here >> pineapple

ECHO is off.
```

When I set variables in CMD, this is what happens.

```
C:\Users\Sahib> set var1 = banana
C:\Users\Sahib> echo %banana%

%banana%
```

C:\Users\Sahib>

Batch variables are completely disabled. WHY!

Comment: Remove the spaces before and after the `=` and the double quotes, and try again.

Comment: Your second example doesn't make sense (you're setting a variable named `var1` and then `echo`ing a different variable named `banana`).

Answer (score 2):

Batch is sensitive to <kbd>Spaces</kbd> on either side of the `=`.

You are, for instance, setting variable derp<kbd>Space</kbd>

Remove those rogue spaces and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your first question. When setting variables, there should not be a space between the "="

```
@echo off
set /p "derp=Enter thing here >> "
echo %derp%
pause > nul
```

And your second problem, when "echoing" variables, you have to echo the variable itself, in this case "var1"

```
C:\Users\Sahib> set var1 = banana
C:\Users\Sahib> echo %banana%
```

should be:

```
 C:\Users\Sahib> set "var1=banana"
 C:\Users\Sahib> echo %var1%
```